# Batch of n-dimensional vectors to batch of images with n channels

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tensor

I have a batch of n-dimensional vectors, i.e. a tensor of size`[batch_size, n]`. I want this to be transformed into a batch of images of size `[batch_size, n, H, W]`, i.e. each element of each vector in the batch must become a `[1, W, H]` image, thus each vector becomes a `[n, H, W]` image.

Now I'm doing it in a very ugly way:

```py
vectors = torch.zeros((batch_size, n))

# This is the (batch_size, n, H, W) tensor that I will fill
channels = torch.empty((batch_size, n, H, W))

for i, vector in enumerate(vectors):
    for j, val in enumerate(vector):
        channels[i, j].fill_(val)
```

How can I do it properly, using pytorch functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add dimensions to the orginal tensor with `vectors[:,:, None, None]`, then multiply by a `(H, W)` tensor of ones:

```
channels = vectors[:,:, None, None]*torch.ones((H, W))
```

This will give you a tensor of size `(batch_size, n, H, W)`, with each `channels[i][j]` being a `(H, W)` map with constant values.